# Hebrew font in Terminal ubuntu 12.10

Tags: command-line, 12.10, fonts

I have files on usb DOK that I can't accesses since the folder name is in Hebrew
I use Ubuntu 12.10

```
ll /media/user/KINGSTON

drwx------  16 user user   8192 Apr 28 16:40 ??????????/


ll /media/ilan/KINGSTON/??????????/
ls: cannot access /media/user/KINGSTON/����������/Hour-Report: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /media/user/KINGSTON/����������/ documents: Input/output error
ls: cannot access /media/user/KINGSTON/����������/files: Input/output error

d?????????  ? ?    ?          ?            ?  documents/
d?????????  ? ?    ?          ?            ? files/
d?????????  ? ?    ?          ?            ? Hour-Report/
```

Comment: What formatting does your usb stick use?

Answer (score 0):

**Terminal > Preferences > Encodings** tab ...

Pinch these *checkboxes* :

- *IBM862 Hebrew*
- *ISO-8859-8 Hebrew Visual*
- *ISO-8859-8-I Hebrew*

**and/or**

- *UTF-8 Unicode*